# z-index não funciona porque?

Tags: html, css

Tenho este código bem simples, a minha `div#d4` está saindo para fora de seu contêiner e caindo dentro da `div#d2` isso porque as `div` filhas não cabem na `div` pai. E ao definir uma `position: absolute` para ela. Ela volta a aparecer, mas porque neste caso o z-index não funciona ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>

        #d1, #d2, #d3, #d0, #d4 {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            color: white;
        }

        #d0 {
            background-color: aqua;
        }

        #d1 {
            background-color: tomato;
        }

        #d2 {
            background-color: green;
        }

        #d3 {
            background-color: blue;
        }

        #d4 {
            background-color: yellow;
            z-index: 1;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="d1">
    content1
    <div id="d0">
        content0
    </div>
    <div id="d4">
        content4
    </div>
</div>

<div id="d2">
    content2
</div>

<div id="d3">
    content2
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

A propriededade [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) só funciona em elementos onde a propriedade `position` está presente e com um dos seguintes valores:

- position: absolute
- position: relative
- position: fixed
- position: sticky

No seu código deve ser:

```css
#d1, #d2, #d3, #d0, #d4 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    color: white;
    position: relative; /* Propriedade position aqui */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade as coisas estão ligadas ao tipo de container ou escopo do elemento. **Se o elemento estiver dentro de um `container flex`, ou `container grid`, vc não precisa declarar o `position` para o `z-index` funcionar.** Mas isso pode depender do que vc pretende com o layout final... e talvez vc nem preciso do `position`

Código em um `Container GRID`

```css
#d1, #d2, #d3, #d0, #d4 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    color: white;
}

#d0 {
    background-color: aqua;
}

#d1 {
    background-color: tomato;

    /* container GRID */
    display: grid;
}

#d2 {
    background-color: green;
}

#d3 {
    background-color: blue;
}

#d4 {
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="d1">
    content1
    <div id="d0">
        content0
    </div>
    <div id="d4">
        content4
    </div>
</div>

<div id="d2">
    content2
</div>

<div id="d3">
    content2
</div>
```

---

Agora em um `Container Flex`

```css
#d1, #d2, #d3, #d0, #d4 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    color: white;
}

#d0 {
    background-color: aqua;
}

#d1 {
    background-color: tomato;

    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#d2 {
    background-color: green;
}

#d3 {
    background-color: blue;
}

#d4 {
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="d1">
    content1
    <div id="d0">
        content0
    </div>
    <div id="d4">
        content4
    </div>
</div>

<div id="d2">
    content2
</div>

<div id="d3">
    content2
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Para qualquer sobre posição deve se colocar o tipo de posição ou seja para que z-index funcione corretamente coloque um **position:** como relative, fixed ou nesmo absolute.