# z-index não funciona

Tags: css, css3

```css
/* CSS Document */
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
*, *:before, *:after, *:active, *:hover {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /*border: 0;*/
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: content-box; /*Comprimir(diminuir) as medidas do elemento para não aumentá-lo quando adicinar margin e padding*/
}
body {
    color: #666;
}
a, a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.centralizado {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
ul.ulHorizontal {
}
ul.ulHorizontal li {
    display: inline-block;
}
ul.ulHorizontal li img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
ul.menuAdmin {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.menuAdmin li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
}
ul.menuAdmin li label {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border : 1px #000 solid;
}
ul.menuAdmin li:first-child {
    border-right: none;
}
ul.menuAdmin li ul {
    display: none;
}
ul.menuAdmin li:hover label {
    border-bottom: none;
}
ul.menuAdmin li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    border : 1px #000 solid;
 z-index: 0;
}
ul.menuAdmin li ul li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
ul.menuAdmin li ul li:not(:first-child) {
    border-top : 1px #000 solid;
}
ul.menuAdmin li ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul.menuCategoria {
    width: 605px;
    border: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
 z-index: 1;
}
ul.menuCategoria li {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border-right: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
}
ul.menuCategoria li a {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
}
ul.menuCategoria li a:hover {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menuAdmin centralizado">
  <li>
   <label>Cadastros</label>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="">Clientes</a></li><!--
  --><li><a href="">Produtos</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li><!--
  --><li>
   <label>Listagens</label>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="">Clientes</a></li><!--
  --><li><a href="">Pedidos</a></li><!--
  --><li><a href="">Produtos</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="menuCategoria ulHorizontal centralizado">
    <li><a href="">Leve</a></li><!--
 --><li><a href="">Pesado</a></li><!--
 --><li><a href="">Todas</a></li>
</ul>
```

O `z-index` não faz as **ul's** que estão nas **li's** da **ul.menuAdmin** sobreporem à **ul.menuCategoria**.

Onde estou **errando**?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [z-index não funciona porque?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/391197/z-index-n%c3%a3o-funciona-porque)

Comment: faltou o position: relative; na ul.menuAdmin li ul. Vou excluir a pergunta. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vc está provavelmente colocando o `z-index` no elemento errado!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que colocando o `z-index` na classe `ul.menuAdmin li:hover ul {}` funciona direitinho

```css
/* CSS Document */
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
*, *:before, *:after, *:active, *:hover {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /*border: 0;*/
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: content-box; /*Comprimir(diminuir) as medidas do elemento para não aumentá-lo quando adicinar margin e padding*/
}
body {
    color: #666;
}
a, a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.centralizado {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
ul.ulHorizontal {
}
ul.ulHorizontal li {
    display: inline-block;
}
ul.ulHorizontal li img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
ul.menuAdmin {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.menuAdmin li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
}
ul.menuAdmin li label {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border : 1px #000 solid;
}
ul.menuAdmin li:first-child {
    border-right: none;
}
ul.menuAdmin li ul {
    display: none;
}
ul.menuAdmin li:hover label {
    border-bottom: none;
}
ul.menuAdmin li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    border : 1px #000 solid;

 z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
ul.menuAdmin li ul li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
ul.menuAdmin li ul li:not(:first-child) {
    border-top : 1px #000 solid;
}
ul.menuAdmin li ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul.menuCategoria {
    width: 605px;
    border: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
 z-index: 1;
}
ul.menuCategoria li {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border-right: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
}
ul.menuCategoria li a {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
}
ul.menuCategoria li a:hover {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menuAdmin centralizado">
<li>
 <label>Cadastros</label>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="">Clientes</a></li><!--
  --><li><a href="">Produtos</a></li>
 </ul>
</li><!--
--><li>
 <label>Listagens</label>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="">Clientes</a></li><!--
  --><li><a href="">Pedidos</a></li><!--
  --><li><a href="">Produtos</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
</ul>

<ul class="menuCategoria ulHorizontal centralizado">
  <li><a href="">Leve</a></li><!--
 --><li><a href="">Pesado</a></li><!--
 --><li><a href="">Todas</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Obrigado, ma coloquei no ul.menuAdmin li ul {} e não no hover. Fiz errado?

Comment: @CarlosRocha no seu caso não faz diferença pq na `ul.menuAdmin li ul {} ` vc já usa `display: none;` então o elemento não aparece de qq forma...

Comment: verdade. obrigado novamente!

Comment: @CarlosRocha tranquilo jovem, se resolveu depois considere marcar a resposta ✔